# How to create a C++ .net .DLL with a namespace but no class

Tags: dll, c++-cli

I am trying to create a DLL to contain a group of functions that I use on a regular basis in C++ .net applications. I believe the best way to arrange these functions is in a namespace, as they don't refer to a specifc object.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    int a();
    int b();
    int c();
}
```

The DLL compiles correctly, but when I try to use the namespace in my client solution, I get the following errror:

```
error C2871: 'MyNamespace' : a namespace with this name does not exist
```

If however I wrap the functions as static methods within a class, my client solution compiles and runs as expected:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public ref class MyClass
    {
    public:
        static int a();
        static int b();
        static int c();
    }
}
```

My assumtion is that the ref keyword is doing something to the class to expose it to the client application.
How do I make a managed/CRL/CLI/.net .DLL using namespace(s) instead of classes(s)?

Comment: What language are you trying to consume this DLL in? C++/CLI also?

Comment: I will definately be using it with C++/CLI and was hoping that it would also work with visual basic and to a lesser extent C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only public methods inside a `public ref class` are ever visible and usable by other managed code.  Your first declarations created functions that are not inside such a class.  This is in general not supported by the CLR, methods *must* exist inside of a class.

The C++/CLI compiler is still happy to compile your code, after all it is common to have such functions in C++ code.  But it must find a suitable home for the code in the functions, it creates a special class to be that home.  It is named `<Module>`, you can see it when you run ildasm.exe on the generated assembly.  This class has an intentionally unusable name, can't use angle brackets in identifiers.  And is marked as *internal* so they are not visible in metadata browsers either.  You can still *link* the functions, in other words you can call them from other C++/CLI source code files.  But not from other managed languages, they don't use a linker.

So use the workaround you found, it is a fine way to expose functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In .NET, there are no "free" functions. Everything is a method of a class. In your case, a static method of a static class, but nevertheless a method of a class.

Comment: It is possible to compile free functions in C++/CLI, so it's more complex than you say. I believe that the compiler places such functions in an implicitly created class with an unspeakable name.